# How to use the same colors for duplicate labels when inserting into histogram

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a histogram metric in Prometheus, and I use that metric on Grafana to display the histogram. I think my question is best explained with an example. If I have a label A and insert the value 10 using the label A. On Grafana, I would see this data point inserted and in the legend I would see the label A with some color. Then if I insert 12 with the label A then Grafana would add a different color for the same label A on the legend. So the legend would have two entries with the same label A, but with different colors.

Instead, I would like all values that use the label A to use one color, all the values that use label B to use another color, and etc. Was wondering if this is possible and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grafana has a transformation called "Labels to fields" which does the following:

> Group series by time and return labels or tags as fields. Useful for
> showing time series with labels in a table where each label key
> becomes a separate column.

This transformation solves the issue I had.